# how create a custom ribbon button to work for both document library and list in share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

As I am very new to SharePoint technology. I have been trying to create a ribbon button to work both in Document library and list. But I am able to create it only in document library it's not displaying in the list. Can anyone please help me to resolve it? I am using following custom action to create the ribbon

```
<CustomAction
    Description="CustomActionDescription"
    Id="NBAD.Ribbon.Library.Actions.MoveFilenetButtonAction"
    RegistrationType="ContentType"
     RegistrationId="0x01"
      Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put "0x" in RegistrationId in order to get your custom action in lists and documents library.